# How do I pass SamAccountName from a given user name, so that I can set -ProtectedfromAccidentalDeletion@$true

Tags: powershell

I inherited several PowerShell scripts, to place a user on LitigationHold in Exchange, as well as set the user's AD protect from accidental deletion to $true.

They all work separately, but one uses User Full name, and the other uses the SAM account name. I am trying to marry scripts so that I can just use the Full name, but I can't seem to pass the SAMAccountName .

My attempt at combining the codes:

```
foreach ($user in ("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3"))
{
    $mailuser = Get-Mailbox $user -DomainController A1.Domain l -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Select *;

    if ($mailuser -eq $null) 
    {
        Write-Host "$user was not found.  Check for misspellings." 
    } 
    else
    {
        if($mailuser.LitigationHoldDate -ne $null) 
        {
            Set-Mailbox $user -LitigationHoldEnabled:$true -Confirm:$False -Force:$True -DomainController A1.Domain;
            Write-Host "$user is now placed on hold."; 
            $userinfo = {
                    Get-ADUser  $user -Server A1.Domain
                }; 
            Set-ADObject -Identity $userinfo.SamAccountName -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion:$true; 
            $i = Get-ADUser $user  -Properties description -Server A1.Domain | 
                %{ $_.description } |
                Set-ADUser $userinfo -Server A1.Domain -Replace @{
                        description="8/19/2019 - Security Hold, please contact admin before modifying `r`n | $($i)"
                    }
        } 
        else{
            Write-Host "$user is already on litigation hold as of $($mailuser.LitigationHoldDate) by $($mailuser.LitigationHoldOwner)."
        }
    }
}
```

To take list of Display names and get usernames:

```
foreach ($user in ("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3"))
{
    $userinfo = Get-ADUser -filter { DisplayName -like $user } -Server A1.Domain ;
    if ($userinfo -ne $null)
    {
        Get-ADUser -filter { DisplayName -like $user } -Server A1.Domain | ft SamAccountName -HideTableHeaders
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$user is not available"
    }
}
```

---

To Add Lit Hold into AD Description

```
foreach ($user in ("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3"))
{
    $mailuser = Get-Mailbox $user -DomainController A1.Domain  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Select *;
    if($mailuser -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Host "$user was not found.  Check for misspellings."
    }
    else
    {
        if ($mailuser.LitigationHoldDate -eq $null)
        {
            $i = Get-ADUser $user  -Properties description -Server A1.Domain  | %{ $_.description};
            Set-ADUser $user -Server A1.Domain  -Replace @{
                    description="Security Hold, please contact the Gnome before modifying `r`n | $($i)"
                }
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "$user is already on litigation hold as of $($mailuser.LitigationHoldDate) by $($mailuser.LitigationHoldOwner)."
        }
    }
}
```

---

To take a list of Display names and set Lit Hold:

```
foreach ($user in ("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3""))
{
    $mailuser = Get-Mailbox $user -DomainController A1.Domain  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Select *;
    if ($mailuser -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Host "$user was not found.  Check for misspellings."
    }
    else
    {
        if($mailuser.LitigationHoldDate -eq $null)
        {
            Set-Mailbox $user -LitigationHoldEnabled:$true -Confirm:$False -Force:$True -DomainController A1.Domain ;
            Write-Host "$user is now placed on hold."
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "$user is already on litigation hold as of $($mailuser.LitigationHoldDate) by $($mailuser.LitigationHoldOwner)."
        }
    }
}
```

---

To take a list of usernames and protect against accidental deletion:

```
"User1", "User2", "User3" | Get-aduser -Server A1.Domain  | Set-ADObject -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion:$true
```

I want to account to be set to LitigationHold, AD protect from accidental deletion, also reflect security hold on description.

This is the error message I get when I run it:

```
FN LN  is now placed on hold.
Set-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the
command again.
At line:9 char:25
+  Set-ADObject -Identity $userinfo.SamAccountName -ProtectedFromAccide ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ADObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADObject

Set-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Get-ADUser  $user -Server A1.domain '.
At line:12 char:1
+ Set-ADUser $userinfo -Server A1.domain  -Replace @ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

I was trying to see if I can bypass the `-Identify` flag by giving it the user full name, but `Set-ADObject` will only take an object, not a string.

---

### --edit 3--

Replying to @Seth about -Identity flag is a parameter:
changed part of the code to give -Identity an ADObject:

```
$userinfo = Get-ADUser  {DisplayName -like $user} -Server A1.domain}; 
Set-ADObject $userinfo -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion:$true;
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Identity' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be
evaluated without input.
At line:8 char:26
+  $userinfo = Get-ADUser  {DisplayName -like $user} -Server A1.domain ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Set-ADObject : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Identity' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be
evaluated without input.
At line:9 char:15
+  Set-ADObject $userinfo -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion:$true;
+               ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Set-ADObject], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADObject

Set-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Get-ADUser  {DisplayName -like $user} -Server A1.domain'.
At line:12 char:1
+ Set-ADUser $userinfo -Server A1.domain  -Replace @ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

I think at this point the issue boils down to: Set-ADUser uses SamAccountName, and I can't seem to parse out the SamAccountName from the user ADObject. I can get the SamAccountName by calling a table from the ADObject, but it will not pass into Set-ADUser correctly.

Comment: If you are getting the correct AD object from your `Get-ADUser`, then the property `sAMAccountName` of the ADUser object contains what you are looking for.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That's what I thought, I passed it like so: `Set-ADObject -Identity $userinfo.SamAccountName ...` from what I read, it should be a distinguished name.

Comment: Once you have an ADObject, you should not need to use any particular field from it to pass to `Set-ADObject`; the `-Identity` or `-Instance` parameter will take an ADObject directly - see [`Set-ADObject` at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adobject?view=win10-ps).

Comment: "To take a list of Display names and set Lit Hold" contains an error, it has two "" for Name 3 at the end. `-Identity` is a parameter not a flag. Why would you not first try to get a proper AD object? What does `$user` actually contain? Displaynames? If so, did you make sure that they match 1:1? `Get-Mailbox` and `Get-ADUser` react differently to just giving it "a name". Why no use what's in "To take list of Display names and get usernames"?

Comment: @Seth Name 3 error was changed. `-Identity` is a parameter, takes in an ADObject, i thought i was passing it the user object, which didn't work, so I did a specific call to sam account name. When I try to pass ADObject an actual object '$userinfo = Get-ADUser  {DisplayName -like $user} -Server A1.domain.', the error message says (see question update at the end). $user actually contains Displaynames (FN LN or FN MI. LN). The match is written at the top as ' if($mailuser -eq $null)'. I'm trying to force "To take list of Display names and get usernames" into the script, which is what i have now.

Comment: While you are checking whenever you get a mailbox you're never verifying whenever you actually get a ADObject. A better way would be to use the Mailbox property `DistinguishedName` and pass that to `Get-AdUser`. I also have to wonder why you'd not using pipes. E.g. `$userinfo | Set-AdUser`. The documentation on [`Get-AdUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) also shows that it accepts more than just an ADObject for `-Identity` (which doesn't include the displayname).

Answer (score 0):

You're currently not doing any verification on whenever you actually get a proper ADUser object. You simply assume that the assignment to `$i`/`$userinfo` will be successful. Your `$name` contains the display name for a user. So for example it would be "John Doe".

This works for [`Get-Mailbox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) because it supports Name, Alias, Distinguished name (DN), Canonical DN, `<domain name>\<account name>`, Email address, GUID, LegacyExchangeDN, SamAccountName, User ID or user principal name (UPN) as values for `Identity`. It has to do this to an extend because some values might or might not be available to identify a mailbox. [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) on the other hand has a much more strict approach only supporting distinguished name, GUID (objectGUID), security identifier (objectSid), SAM account name (sAMAccountName). Hence using the display name to find an AD account isn't supported. Your colleague used a filter to just use it anyway which is one solution `$userinfo = Get-ADUser -filter { DisplayName -like $user } -Server A1.Domain ;`.

If you really want to go with the display name you'll need to either look for it like that or use the `DistinguishedName` property of the mailbox to get the owner. So you'd do something like:

```
$mailbox = Get-Mailbox test
$adObject = Get-AdUser -Identity $mailbox.DistinguishedName
```

Obviously you should check whenever the property actually exists on the mailbox object as it might be disconnected. Also rather than using `$user` again and again you might want to use actual object (e.g. the mailbox or AD Object) to make sure you only need to verify your search results once.

You should also be able to just use one `Set-AdUser` call instead of that very weird call you're currently doing. You find the user, iterate the descriptions for the user (an object only has one) and add to it. Doing something like `Set-AdUser $adObject -Description "New Description | $($adObject.Description)"` would be much shorter and clearer. Spreading it some more might even improve it more.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try and recode this instead of just mashing the few scripts together, maybe even do it the correct way like you pointed. Thanks!

Comment: No problem but checkout the help section on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you comments are usually removed at some point. You can keep most of the logic from your colleague but adding some basic error handling and maybe having a look at what the code actually does goes a long way.